# What is the best way to wrap divs so that they take the remaining space?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container, which contains blocks inside. The number of the blocks and their height can be different, but the width is 45% for all, so that two blocks can fit into one row. I currently use `flexbox` with `flex-wrap: wrap`, but there is an issue, which you can see on the screenshot below. The wanted result is the one on the right. How can that be achieved?

[image: Example]

HTML:

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .block {
      width: 45%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: grey;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="block" style="height: 500px;"></div>
      <div class="block" style="height: 200px;"></div>
      <div class="block" style="height: 100px;"></div>
      <div class="block" style="height: 300px;"></div>
      <div class="block" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure about for specific use case, maybe this [`dense` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) might help

Comment: As there are javascript libraries to achieve this [masonary effect](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html), I doubt it can currently be done with HTML and CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is quite tricky and might be close to impossible but there's a way to somehow do it. If your container's height is fixed at some point, you can just set the flex-direction of your container to `column` then set the max height for the container as a brake point to go to new column. See sample code below. You can run it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 900px;
}

.block {
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" style="height: 500px;"></div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 300px;"></div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I was also considering this, but the height should be flexible.